# What is the difference between Query Studio and Report Studio in Cognos?

Tags: business-intelligence, cognos, cognos-8, cognos-bi, cognos-tm1

***What is the difference between Query Studio and Report Studio in Cognos?***

Could anyone explain me in detail?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Query studio is lightweight add hoc web report writer that allows semi-power users to build ad-hoc reports via the Cognos web portal using prepared data content published to the web portal.  Users can sort/filter change font size, do some grouping and aggregation... and save their reports. How ever this report writer is lightweight in that you don't have strong capabilities over presentation format and layout.... in comes report studio which is the enterprise report development tool which can develop pixel perfect reports that have a high degree of interactivity complex condition/conditional layout processing etc...  Report studio can edit query studio reports as well.  So sometimes users save their Query studio reports but ask for developers to tweak them to get desired appearance/functionality.  Both application generate XML files that are stored in the Cognos Repository.